# How do I search table/object list in SSDT?

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools

I really like to use SSDT inside of VS to work with databases instead of firing up SSMS and do the job there. IMHO SSMS is for DB admins and DB devs. However, as a .NET dev, I only need to peek at the DB on relatively rare occasions so I prefer to stay within VS and just switch to the SQL Server Object Explorer and browse the DB objects.

This is all fine, but when it comes to bigger DBs, with hundreds+ of objects I cannot seem to figure out how can I filter the object list in the SQL Server Object Explorer window. Neither can I find such a question and answer anywhere on SO/The Internet. Am I searching it wrong or really this simple feature is missing from the SSDT?

I'm looking for a function similar to Solution Search in the Solution Explorer but anything else goes too.

Comment: what stops you to search via Solution explorer?

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev SQL Server Object Explorer lists connections to physical DB servers and their content. I want to search through its objects and not through objects under a `sqlproj`

Comment: Use redgate sql search for that. it is free and it supports visual studio and ssms  as well. There is no native functionality for that.